# I have a delta in specific records in same table - how do I find that specific row?

Tags: delta

I have a table A which contains list of counties for a given year along with other records.

Columns are 'Year' and 'CountyName'.

For 2020, there are 6434 'Counties' listed and for 2019, 6433 'Counties' are listed (in the same table).

How do I find the CountyName that is missing in 2019?

I can ofcourse run a simple query to get these records individually and then find out the missing county but I am trying to check if it can be done at the query level.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with the usage of the not in function or the exist one.
Something like:

```
Select countryname from table where year =2019 and countryname not in (Select countryname from table where year =2020)
```